# zsh tab completion to run scripts in current folder (.<TAB>scr<TAB>)->./script.sh

Tags: zsh, tab-completion, oh-my-zsh

I have an issue with zsh (or oh-my-zsh):

When I want to run a script in current directory, I do `./script.sh`. In bash I could do `.<TAB>` and it would give me `./` where I could continue typing the script name `./sc<TAB>` which would end up with `./script.sh`

Now the problem is that when I do `.<TAB>` in zsh, I get a list of alternatives where none of them are `./`.

The reason I'm not just typing `./` is that it's quite cumbersome on a Norwegian keyboard layout: `.` then `SHIFT+7`. Makes me feel inefficient :)

I've tried with `zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true` and some options like

```
setopt autolist
unsetopt menucomplete `
```

But nothing seems to work for me.

I'm quite new to this, so I'd really appreciate any help solving this!

Comment: I know this annoying `SHIFT+7` too well... some time ago I mapped one of these useless windows keys `;)` to `/`. Since then it's real fun to type `//////////`. Perhaps that's an option for you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to tweak the completion system, so that it expands `.` always to `./`. But here is a workaround for the special case you have described, i.e. at the beginning of the command line:

```
expand-or-complete-special-dot() {
  if [[ $BUFFER == "." ]]; then
    LBUFFER="./"          
  fi 
  zle expand-or-complete
}
zle -N expand-or-complete-special-dot
bindkey "^I" expand-or-complete-special-dot
```

This is a wrapper for the normal `expand-or-complete` function which is (by default) bound to `TAB`.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly the behaviour I want :)